# Can I answer questions on other Stack Exchange sites to get unbanned?

Tags: support, post-ban

I want to contribute answers that get upvoted so I can get my ban lifted. The problem is I can't answer a lot of these programming questions.

Is there any way I can answer questions on the other Stack Exchange websites and get unbanned from Stack Overflow?

Comment: Nope sorry. Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998

Comment: Looking at your suspension notice, I would just serve the 4 more days to 'cool down'.

Answer (score 17):

No, the automated question and answer blocks are per-site and participation on other sites has no effect (positive or negative) on it.

Comment: This might make an interesting feature request. It would arguably make sense to allow users make up for their "sins" on another SE site where they know something about the topic, and can make better contributions. If they can make it on a different SE site, they will have learned the ropes of how the system works. (of course, if they continue to produce garbage on some other SE site and get blocked *again*, they probably need to be kicked out completely)

Comment: @perhapsPekka That would be _extremely_ expensive to implement. These checks are calculated on the fly when someone posts a question or answer (on sites where they are enabled), thus this would mean aggregating across N sites, where N is the number of sites where the user had an account. At _best_ it would be extremely slow. It's a bit of a novel idea, though - I don't think it's off base. It's just going to be one whopper of an implementation.

Comment: @TimPost it must be noted, however, that Stack Overflow has more questions than all other sites _combined_ (if I look correctly). Would it make sense to combine the per-site databases into a larger one upon which one could run aggregated cross-network queries? I'm pretty sure this is not the only case when one would want to run a cross-network query.

Comment: @TimPost: How about using the site only query to check for a ban, if one is found check a daily cached value of whether the ban should be lifted according to other-site activity?

Comment: We do have network wide queries to run (mostly for reporting purposes), but there's no problem running these serially, in fact it's quite easy for us to do. The payoff here doesn't really justify the work of combining the sites into one massive DB, technical concerns completely ignored. The other issue is what Undo points out in his answer, we're talking about totally different communities and topics. All we can derive is a sense of how articulate one might be, not their prowess for asking questions about cooking as a mechanic.

Answer (score 10):

No. The automated post bans for low-quality content are separated per-site. Therefore, each site pretty much knows nothing about your activities on other sites.

Here's an example: I get post banned on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com). I then begin providing extremely high quality contributions on [English Language and Usage](https://ELU.stackexchange.com). What does this say? It means that I know how to ask high-quality questions *about English*. It does not, however, mean I know how to write good Physics questions.

What you need to do is **edit** your existing questions and answers and try to get some upvotes on them. Once the system gets enough indications that you are providing high-quality content, you will be unbanned.

Comment: Can't you also provide good quality answers to eventually get yourself unbanned from asking questions? (I've heard about that, but I don't actually know, and it would make sense for cases where one's questions are beyond rescue)

Comment: One would certainly think you could - from what I know, the system takes into account *overall* post quality. Therefore, you should be able to dig yourself out through that route.