# Got unbanned from asking question and good positive reaction to my next question and still got banned again

Tags: support, post-ban, ban

Recently I saw that I got unbanned from asking question and so I asked a question...

I got a good positive reaction to the question but I looked at the "ask a question" and it blocked it to me again... Anyone know why and whats the problem? Why would it block it to me again?

Comment: I think the ban was replaced with a strict rate limiting, e.g. users with bad history can ask one question every week or even month. I believe you hit that limit, and not a total ban. What message exactly do you get?

Comment: You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: So that's it. I'll find the proper dupe.

Comment: Well it's this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242369/how-did-i-get-unbanned-i-did-not-get-any-upvotes but on second look, the one gnat and @Servy found it fitting and newer, so leaving it be. Anyway, the answer to your question here is in both.

Comment: Thanks thats the correct dupe...

Comment: Well, Shog also mentions the rolling rate limit, so his answer is more complete.

Comment: Just curious and totally off topic, why aren't you a banana here? (by name ;))

Comment: But still when will this limitation that I have on my account will be lifted? Should I open new account? I don't want to be punished on mistake that I did long time ago...

Comment: I have no idea

Comment: Hopefully with your good recent record, one or two days, but it might be longer, we can't know. My advice is that if in two days you still can't ask, click the "contact us" in the footer, choose "Other", put your email address, and explain what's going on, asking for help from the team itself.

Comment: Ok will do! Thank you!

Comment: Opening a new account with your rate limits, it would make it worst, a great deal worst